# Adding more items below ListView

Tags: flutter

I have some list of items inside a ListView. All the listitems vanishes when adding another ListView or even a container with height after the existing ListView items.

```
Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: theme.primaryColor,
              child: Scrollbar(
                /*isAlwaysShown: true,*/
                thumbVisibility: false,
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: ListView(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    children: categoriesWidgets!,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I have tried adding column and showing them inside a children but still no success. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shrinkWrap property of listview builder or gridview builder

```
GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
    )

ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
    )
```

For more details run this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text(
            "Title",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3, crossAxisSpacing: 10, mainAxisSpacing: 10),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              child: Text(
                data[index],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          const Text(
            "Title",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: ListTile(
                tileColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                title: Text(
                  data[index],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```